# Converting data frame column from character to numeric

Tags: r

I have a data frame that I construct as such:

```
> yyz <- data.frame(a = c("1","2","n/a"), b = c(1,2,"n/a"))

> apply(yyz, 2, class)
      a           b 
"character" "character"
```

I am attempting to convert the last column to numeric while still maintaining the first column as a character.  I tried this:

```
> yyz$b <- as.numeric(as.character(yyz$b))
> yyz
  a  b
  1  1
  2  2
  n/a NA
```

But when I run the apply class it is showing me that they are both character classes.

```
> apply(yyz, 2, class)
      a           b 
"character" "character"
```

Am I setting up the data frame wrong? Or is it the way R is interpreting the data frame?

Comment: Note that `class(yyz$b)` yields `"numeric"` in this example. Therefore the column *is* in fact numeric. As pointed out by @akrun, the apparent mismatch of classes results from the use of `apply()`.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If we need only one column to be `numeric`

```
yyz$b <- as.numeric(as.character(yyz$b))
```

But, if all the columns needs to changed to `numeric`, use `lapply` to loop over the columns and convert to `numeric` by first converting it to `character` class as the columns were `factor`.

```
yyz[] <- lapply(yyz, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Both the columns in the OP's post are `factor` because of the string `"n/a"`.  This could be easily avoided while reading the file using `na.strings = "n/a"` in the `read.table/read.csv` or if we are using `data.frame`, we can have `character` columns with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` (the default is `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`)

---

Regarding the usage of `apply`, it converts the dataset to `matrix` and `matrix` can hold only a single class.  To check the `class`, we need

```
lapply(yyz, class)
```

Or

```
sapply(yyz, class)
```

Or check

```
str(yyz)
```

Comment: This converts both columns to numeric.  I only want column b to be numeric.  I specifiy yyz$b <- lapply(yyz$b, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))), it will turn them into lists

Comment: @Dexstrum It is because you are assigning a list to a column.  If we need only a single column as numeric, use the same syntax as you did `yyz$b <- as.numeric(as.character(yyz$b))`

Comment: Please look again at what I posted.  I already tried that, and it did not change the column to numeric.

Comment: After running the sapply(yyz, clas) it shows up as numeric.  Thank you.

Comment: @Dexstrum It should change the column to `numeric` as the character elements are changed to NA.  If `sapply(yyz, class)` show up as numeric, isn't that you wanted?