# Importing CSV into R - numeric values read as integer

Tags: r

I am aware that there are similar questions on this site, however, none of them seem to answer my question sufficiently.

I have to read a CSV file containing numeric values which decimal separator is the comma.

Using `data <- read.table("~/file.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";",stringsAsFactors=FALSE, dec=",")` values are reported as numeric but they actually are integer loosing all decimal information.

Using `data <- read.table("~/file.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` values are reported correctly but readed as *chr* data so It's impossible to perform a linear regression on it. Also transforming *chr* to *num* as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37707060/converting-data-frame-column-from-character-to-numeric) end with *NA Coercion*

I am EU based so I have also tried to load the dataset using `read.csv2` but this can't solve the problem.

- EDIT:
  Here a sample of the CSV file I'm trying to load:

[image: sample of the CSV file I'm trying to load]

- EDIT2:Excerpt of dataframe. I can't paste all values because they are >10000

> ```
>  AV_TOTAL          LIVING_AREAM2        DIST_PARKS 
>     632800               84,73               23,88
> ```

Comment: It is difficult to see why your first code example would not work, provided that the data is correctly formatted and specified as in the code. It would help to see some or all of your CSV file.

Comment: Adding my voice to to @neilfws. A single line of your csv file (outside the header) might prove helpful, in order to help you out.

Comment: Example data as plain text please, not images - we need to be able to copy/paste.

Comment: Is EDIT2 the data frame after reading into R ? If so, we need to see the CSV before reading into R.

Answer (score 0):

"read_delim" and "read_csv" functions from readr package have an argument named "locale" which is set to default_locale() by default. You can change decimal seperator by setting this argument to:

```
locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",")
```