# how to convert a column to numeric while it contains both strings and numbers as strings

Tags: r, dataframe, number-formatting

I have a data frame in which there is column that I want to use to join with another data frame. The column contains number as string and strings such as follows:

```
x<-data.frame(referenceNumber=c("80937828","gdy","12267133","72679267","72479267"))
```

How Can I convert the numbers as string to numeric and replace the strings with zeros/null?

I tried `x %>% mutate_if(is.character,as.numeric)`

But it returns the following error :

> ```
> "Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
>   no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "character""
> ```

Comment: How would your expected output look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting data frame column from character to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37707060/converting-data-frame-column-from-character-to-numeric)

Comment: Also can't reproduce your error. What R and `dplyr` versions are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could try just using `as.numeric`, which would assign `NA` to any non numeric entry in the vector.  Then, we can selectively replace the `NA` values with zero:

```
x <- c("80937828","gdy","12267133","72679267","72479267")
output <- as.numeric(x)
output[is.na(output)] <- 0
output

[1] 80937828        0 12267133 72679267 72479267
```

Edit based on the comment by @Sotos: If the column/vector is actually `factor`, then it would have to be cast to character in order for my answer above to work.

Comment: OP has a data frame which seems to have the `referenceNumber` as a `factor`, which will need `as.character` prior to numeric

Answer (score 0):

I'd check for NAs in an `ifelse` construction:

```
x<-data.frame(referenceNumber=c("80937828","gdy","12267133","72679267","72479267"), stringsAsFactors = F)

x$referenceNumber <- ifelse(!is.na(as.numeric(x$referenceNumber)), x$referenceNumber, 0)
```

This only works if your strings are not factors. Otherwise you need to add `as.character` first.

Answer (score 0):

Probably due the referenceNumber is factor:

```
x<-data.frame(referenceNumber=c("80937828","gdy","12267133","72679267","72479267"), stringsAsFactors=F)
str(x)
#'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ referenceNumber: chr  "80937828" "gdy" "12267133" "72679267" ...
xx<-x %>% mutate_if(is.character,as.numeric)
#Warning message:
#In evalq(as.numeric(referenceNumber), <environment>) :
#  NAs introduced by coercion
xx
#  referenceNumber
#1        80937828
#2              NA
#3        12267133
#4        72679267
#5        72479267
str(xx)
#'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ referenceNumber: num  80937828 NA 12267133 72679267 72479267
```