# Error in plot.window(…): need finite 'xlim' values but it seems all fine

Tags: r, csv, plot, dataset

I have this dataset of wines, in the following format:

[Format image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0WgA.png)

When I try to plot the quality column using:

```
plot( redWineData$quality)
```

where redWineData is:

```
redWineData <- read.csv('winequality-red.csv')
```

I get the following error :

> Error in plot.window(…): need finite 'xlim' values.

Why is that?

The table is as follows:

```
   fixedAcidity;  volatileAcidity;     citricAcid;    residualSugar;   chlorides;    freeSulfur dioxide;    total sulfur dioxide;    density;    pH;   sulphates;   alcohol;    quality
1;      7.4;             0.7;              0;              1.9;           0.076;    11;             34;           0.9978;    3.51;  0.56;       9.4;       5
2;  7.8;        0.88;          0;          2.6;           0.098;    25;         67;           0.9968;    3.2;   0.68;       9.8;       5
3;  7.8;        0.76;        0.04;         2.3;       0.092;    15;         54;           0.997;     3.26;  0.65;       9.8;       5
```

Also the dput output is:

```
structure(list(X.fixedAcidity.volatileAcidity.citricAcid.residualSugar.chlorides.freeSulfur.dioxide.total.sulfur.dioxide.density.pH.sulphates.alcohol.quality = c("1;7.4;0.7;0;1.9;0.076;11;34;0.9978;3.51;0.56;9.4;5", 
"2;7.8;0.88;0;2.6;0.098;25;67;0.9968;3.2;0.68;9.8;5", "3;7.8;0.76;0.04;2.3;0.092;15;54;0.997;3.26;0.65;9.8;5", 
";;;;;;;;;;;;", ";;;;;;;;;;;;", ";;;;;;;;;;;;", ";;;;;;;;;;;;"
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Those values look like characters to me (they're left aligned). Please post the output of `dput(redWineData)` in the question.

Comment: Can you please post your data snippet as text (i.e. cut-and-paste into a code block) rather than as an image/screenshot?  (A [mcve] would be very helpful ...)

Comment: Also, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37707117/8245406). This is probably a duplicate.

Comment: best guess is that your column names ended up with embedded spaces, i.e. the column name is "   quality" rather than "quality", so that `redWineData$quality` is NULL.  You could just try printing `redWineData$quality` and see what you get ...

Comment: @RuiBarradas, I don't think factor/character vs numeric confusion can explain this one ...

Comment: Done! All the info is on the post!

Comment: Also, I'm using the red wine data from this link: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine+Quality, but I'm trying with fewer rows

Comment: The problem is the columns separator. `read.csv` expects a comma, I have tried `sep = ";"` and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the delimiter in the file is a semi-colon rather than a comma. You should have used:

```
redWineData <- read.delim('winequality-red.csv')  # European styled .csv
```

Then the dataframe would have a column named `quality`. At the moment you have a single column named: "X.fixedAcidity.volatileAcidity.citricAcid.residualSugar.chlorides.freeSulfur.dioxide.total.sulfur.dioxide.density.pH.sulphates.alcohol.quality"

Comment: That was so clear! Thanks for the explanation!